# What the point of using std::ios_base::binary?

Tags: c++, stl, iostream, eol

I had a issue with Linux file reading under Window. Here is the issue discussion: [Using fstream::seekg under windows on a file created under Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973274/using-fstreamseekg-under-windows-on-a-file-created-under-unix/26992855#26992855).

The issue was workarounded by opening the **text** file with `std::ios_base::binary` specified.

But what's the actual point with this mode? If specified, you can still work with your file as a text file (writting with `mystream << "Hello World" << std::endl` and reading with `std::getline`).

Under Windows, the only difference, I could notice is that `mystream << "Hello World" << std::endl` uses:

- `0x0D 0x0A` as line separator if `std::ios_base::binary` was not specified (EOL and carriage return)
- `0x0A` as line separator if `std::ios_base::binary` was specified (EOL only)

Notepad does not smartly show lines when opening the files generated with `std::ios_base::binary`. Better editors like vi or Wordpad does show them.

Is that really the only difference there is between files generated with and without `std::ios_base::binary`? Documentation says `Consider stream as binary rather than text.`, what does this mean in the end?

Is it safe to always set `std::ios_base::binary` if I don't care about opeing the file in Notepad and want to have `fstream::seekg` always work?

Comment: I would also test with `\0` characters in the strings too. In binary those are probably just outputted, while for non-binary they might be interpreted as a string terminator.

Comment: @GáborBakos If the only systems concerned are Unix and Windows, then the only differences are the line endings and 0x1A, which Windows treats as an end of file character, at least on input.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The differences between binary and text modes are implementation
defined, but only concern the lowest level: they do not change the
meaning of things like `<<` and `>>` (which insert and extract textual
data).  Also, formally, outputting all but a few non-printable
characters (like `'\n'`) is undefined behavior if the file is in text
mode.

For the most common OSs: under Unix, there is no distinction; both are
identical.  Under Windows, `'\n'` internally will be mapped to the two
character sequence CR, LF (0x0D, 0x0A) externally, and 0x1A will be
interpreted as an end of file when reading.  In more exotic (and mostly
extinct) OSs, however, they could be represented by entirely different
file types at the OS level, and it could be impossible to read a file in
text mode if it were written in binary mode, and vice versa.  Or you
could see something different: extra white space at the end of line, or
no `'\n'` in binary mode.

With regards to always setting `std::ios_base::binary`: my policy for
portable files is to decide exactly how I want them formatted, set
binary, and output what I want.  Which is often CR, LF, rather than just
LF, since that's the network standard.  On the other hand, *most*
Windows programs have no problems with just LF, but I've encountered
more than a few Unix programs which have problems with CR, LF; which
argues for systematically using just LF (which is easier, too).  Doing
things this way means that I get the same results regardless of whether
I'm running under Unix or under Windows.

Comment: Do I understand well that setting `std::ios_base::binary` or not for file **reading** makes no difference (except fixing the bug referenced above) and setting `std::ios_base::binary` or not for file **writting** may lead to differences based on the platform?

Comment: @jpo38 No.  The choice between binary and text affects both reading and writing: under Windows, when reading, a CR,LF will be mapped to an LF, and a 0x1A will cause reading to to stop.  And on some exotic systems, an open in binary mode may fail if the file was written in text, or vice versa.

Comment: @JamesKanze -- I think others have commented that (at least on MacOS) the stream operators IGNORE binary mode if you have it set: that means if you use ">>" (the extract formatting operator) to read in binary data from a stream, you will see CR,LF expansion/conversion even though you might NOT have expected this with binary mode!  I chased down complex binary file format bugs introduced from the use of ">>".  Those issues were easily solved by using a plain read().

Answer (score 2):

I found (by loosing two hour of work trying to understand what was going on) a situation where specifying `std::ios_base::binary` does make a huge difference.

```
std::vector<char> data{ 0x01, 0x02, 0x0A, 0x0B };
{
    std::fstream tfat;
    tfat.open( "binary", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary );
    tfat.write( &(data[0]), data.size() );
    tfat.close();
}
{
    std::fstream tfat;
    tfat.open( "not_binary", std::ios_base::out );
    tfat.write( &(data[0]), data.size() );
    tfat.close();
}
```

Then, "binary" file contains 4 bytes: `0x01, 0x02, 0x0A, 0x0B`
But "not_binary" file contains 5 bytes: `0x01, 0x02, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0B`

0x0D (`\r`) was inserted before 0x0A (`\n`). While I write 4 bytes, I expected to have 4 bytes in the file in the end.

So this make me realize why `std::ios_base::binary` must be used when writting data to a file, even if not using `<<` operator.

Comment: I tried on my linux machine and I cannot reproduce the result. Both files contain the 4 bytes as expected with no extra byte. I understand that this is somehow related with particular text formatting on windows systems, but the fact that if you forget `ios::binary` you may get random stuff in the output, is super scary.

Comment: @DarioP: I confirm I was using Windows when I tested that

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of text stream vs binary stream is platform-specific and somewhat unpredictable.

But as far as popular platforms go, it's easy: On Linux and MacOS X, there is no difference. On Windows, the only difference is that internal `\n` is translated to `\r\n` in the external stream.

Comment: Under Windows, a 0x1A will be treated as end of file in text mode.