# seekg() before each .get() call VS seekg() before for loop

Tags: c++, text-files, ifstream, seekg

I am just trying to read simple text file with **ifstream**. Suppose my **text file** looks like this (I don't know how to properly format it here, so here is how I wrote it notepad):
**a\tb\nc\t\d\n**

Output from reading text file using **.seekg()** before each **.get()** differs from output when **.seekg()** is called only before for loop (see output).

## Question:

Is this expected behaviour? If yes then why is it happening?

## Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    ifstream myfile("test.txt");
    if (myfile)
    {

        cout << "Using seekg before each myfile.get():" << endl;
        cout << "***********************" << endl;
        myfile.seekg(0);
        cout << (char)myfile.get();
        myfile.seekg(1);
        cout << (char)myfile.get();
        myfile.seekg(2);
        cout << (char)myfile.get();
        myfile.seekg(3);
        cout << (char)myfile.get();
        myfile.seekg(4);
        cout << (char)myfile.get() << endl;
        cout << "***********************" << endl;

        cout << "Using seekg only before loop:" << endl;
        cout << "***********************" << endl;
        myfile.seekg(0);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            cout << (char)myfile.get();
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "***********************" << endl;

        myfile.close();
    }

}
```

## Output:

[Output after running above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfOAI.png)

## After debugging:

In text file:

- a is at position 0
- '\t' is at position 1
- b is at position 2
- *when **.seekg(3)** is used right before **.get()** then **.get()** returns '\n'*
- *when **.seekg(4)** is used right before **.get()** then **.get()** returns '\n' also*
- *when **.seekg(0)** is used only before for loop (see code) then **.get()** only returns single '\n' at position 3/4 , meaning '\n' is at the position 3 and 'c' is at position 4*

Comment: If you run it on Windows, you might want `ifstream myfile("test.txt", ios::binary);`. See [What the point of using std::ios_base::binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26993086/what-the-point-of-using-stdios-basebinary) for additional info.

Comment: @273K You are totally right, that fixed my problem